# Regex expression is not capturing my entire selection

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with a tokenized string, the token always begins with ~~Example~~ and ends with ~~end~~.  I am trying to work out a regex expression that will grab both tokens.  I currently have /~~([^])\w+~~/ but this is only grabbing the end token which is ~~end~~.  The following example will clarify my question.

**Current Regex expression** `/~~([^])\w+~~/`

**Example text:**

~~/Document Heading 1~~
[Paragraph 1 /Document Heading 1]Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus
~~end~~

**Current result:**
I am currently only grabbing the last token ~~end~~ with the current expression.

**Desired result:**
I would like both ~~/Document Heading 1~~ and ~~end~~ , however, it is important to point out that the beginning of this token "~~/Document Heading 1~~" can contain anything between ~~ however the ending of the token "~~end~~" will always be the same.

Comment: If the end token is always the same, why do you still want to grab it?

Comment: the idea is I want to segment the incoming context that may have different headers in columns which I can the use to insert it into a word doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use 2 regex to match anything between 2 mutlicharacter delimiters.

A lazy matching solution:

```
/~~([^]*?)~~/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY4zT6/1). This can be written as `/~~([\s\S]*?)~~/g`, too, and captures any 0+ characters between leading `~~` and trailing `~~` as few as possible.

Another way is by using negated character classes (to unroll the lazy matching pattern):

```
/~~([^~]*(?:~(?!~)[^~]*)*)~~/g
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sY4zT6/2). This alternative is good to use if the strings you  have a very long. The `[^~]*` matches 0+ chars other than `~`, and `(?:~(?!~)[^~]*)*` matches 0+ sequences of a `~` that is not followed with another `~` and then 0+ chars other than `~`.

```js
var re = /~~([^]*?)~~/g; 
var str = '~~/Document Heading 1~~\n[Paragraph 1 /Document Heading 1]Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus\n~~end~~ \n';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: ++ for the lazy match.  also have never seen not used like that before.

Answer (score 3):

`/~~(.|[\r\n])*?~~/`

should work for you (assuming you set greedy flag of course)

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is fine, you have my vote.

Comment: It will not match newlines between `~~`s. I did not downvote anyway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it matches newlines if you add the m flag like i mentioned in the parens :)

Comment: In Ruby, `m` modifier is a DOTALL modifier, in JS, it redefines `^` and `$` anchor behavior.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh wow, wasnt aware of that js regex behavior.  thanks for the enlightenment.  just adding an or in there and including carriage return and newline still makes this the simplest approach i believe though :)

Comment: To be clear, it's more specific to ruby, most of regex engines use `s` as DOTALL/singleline modifier. Unfortunately, s doesn't exist in Javascript and is replaced by `[\s\S]` or `[^]`

Comment: There aren't greedy flag or ungreedy flag in Javascript. As far I know there's only a U flag *(that means ungreedy)* in PCRE and that inverts the behaviour of quantifiers *(`.*` becomes non-greedy, `.*?` becomes greedy)*. If you are speaking about the g flag, it doesn't mean "greedy", it means "global" *(=search all matches in the string)*. Note that in general using this type of construct `(A|B)*` isn't very efficient with a backtracking regex engine and may cause a catastrophic backtracking if the subpattern after fails *(however if you use that with grep/sed/mySQL there's no problem)*

Comment: The pattern you suggest is very inefficient. See [this regex in action with a fake string](https://regex101.com/r/eN2mP8/1). And [here is my second regex](https://regex101.com/r/eN2mP8/2) with the same string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew point taken.  But i would point out that in those examples, javascript flavor isnt set and some performance is gained just by evaluating the regex under javascript flavor.  I would also say that from the OP's question it is unclear how important performance is to the requested solution so the readability of the less performant regex may or may not be a fair trade off in this case :)

Comment: I think you refer to the fact I chose PCRE. JS performance is similar in these cases. I chose PCRE demo for better illustration.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

this might work if you use it **globally**

```
(~~.*?~~)
```

**~~** matches the characters ~~ literally

**.*?** matches any character (except newline)

Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]

**~~** matches the characters ~~ literally

g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

if you haven't already checked it out https://regex101.com/ is a great resource for testing out these expressions

Comment: It's simple and works well since there isn't probably no newlines between `~~` and `~~`

Answer (score 2):

In your regexp you are missing the tilde char inside the squar brachets:

`/~~([^~]+)~~/mg`

You could test your expressions in:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Just a note: this won't match `~~/Document~1 here~~`

Comment: Right, thanks. Actually I did't though about a possible `~` inside the matching part.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
(~~.*?~~)(?:.|\n|\r)*?(~~end~~)
```

OutPut

```
Match 1
1.  ~~/Document Heading 1~~
2.  ~~end~~
Match 2
1.  ~~/Document Heading 1~~
2.  ~~end~~
```

Groups will have your start and end values

Comment: Just a note: this won't match `~~/Document~1 here~~`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew addressed your comment :) please let me know if i'm missing something

Comment: I do not think your answer misses anything since the question is a bit unclear :) However, your regex does not allow newline in the `(~~[^\r\n]+~~)`. Also, there seems to be no need of a non-capturing group (you donot use any quantifier on it.

Comment: Why do you believe a newline isn't possible in the content between `~~start~~` and `~~end~~`? And why the non-capturing group?

Comment: Updated the answer @CasimiretHippolyte forgot to remove that non-capturing group while copying thing from rubular(was trying many things with that)

Comment: Take care that the dot `.` doesn't match `\n`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that's a bummer :D i didn't know that,  I thought `. `matches everything. Updated answer